# jQuery toggle show/hide - div shows but does not expand

Tags: show-hide, jquery

I have a little menu that should expand to reveal the HTML below, which is hidden at present.

Following jQuery:

```
$('.mobileMenu').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('arrowDown').next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

This piece of code works great on [this page](http://www.haselden.co.uk/rttest/inner.html) (click the "hide" feature on the left col)

However I need to utilise the same feature with my menu for "mobile width".

If you resize your browser down to 320 or so and go [here](http://www.haselden.co.uk/rttest/index.html) you'll see the menu is just +menu (bit smashy at the mo but working). Click it, and the menu does expand to show the links, the first being "shop online" but for some reason they are hidden/not showing. Ideally the green `navigation` div should expand

Answer (score 0):

The rest of your menu items need `display: block` , at the moment only the top item has it.

Comment: But it's currently "display:none;" so that the full menu doesn't show. Putting it as display:block would make the entire menu appear and completely defeat the purpose of the jQuery

Comment: Setting `display:none` on DOM elements makes it difficult for the browser to properly calculate the dimensions of hidden elements (unless you have an explicit width or height set ), it's usually better to set the 'visibility' property to 'hidden'. However, if you're just toggling between css classes, 'display:none'

Comment: should work fine. From what I remember it appeared like `display:block` was only added to one `menu-item` and the remainder had no `display` property set.